# SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I am trying to work with a SQL Server database in C# using VS 2017 but I got stuck.

(EDITED QUESTION)

I am following these steps:

I installed SSMS (SQL Express) and created a database with that

I connect to that database from Visual Studio 2017

I can work with this database easily in the Server Explorer, create tables, create queries, etc.

But when I want to connect and work with it in C# I cannot go ahead. I am using the following code:

```
{
    var db = Database.Open("myconnection");
    var sql = "Select Count(*) from Table1";
    var Initialcount = db.QueryValue(sql);
}
```

At this point I receive the following error:
System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.'

The connection string in web.config is:

```
<add name ="myconnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=vdatabase"/>
```

I have not been able to solve this problem.

Comment: Please show us what your **connection string** looks like - most probably stored in the `web.config` (or `app.config`) configuration file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a provider. 
**Please add the providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"** or whatever provider are you using to the end of the connection string as follows:

`<add name ="myconnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=vdatabase" providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"/>`
Also you will need some credentials to access the db. It could be windows authentication (Integrated authentication) or the user name and password of the db.
Please comment your results.

Comment: I missed the example. There it is now.

Comment: It worked. I added Integrated Security=true and then it worked. Thank you very much